# How to create a Reset button using Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to create a reset button that allows me to reset username details if clicked. How can I achieve this please?

I have tried different methods but I get

> Name Error: enter name is not defined

```
main_window_page = Tk()
main_window_page.title("GA")
main_window_page.geometry("600x600")

entername = StringVar()
enterpassword = StringVar()

Username=tk.Label(text="Username")
Username.pack(pady=1,padx=1)
EnterName=tk.Entry(bd=4,textvariable=entername)
EnterName.pack(pady=5,padx=5)

Reset=tk.Button(text="Reset",command=clearFunc)
Reset.pack(pady=13,padx=13)

main_window_page.mainloop()

def clearFunc():
  entername.set("0")
```

Comment: just create put in `clearfunc` --> `entername .set(" ")` and the function has to be declared before his call

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow Tobi.

You need to make entername a global string variable so that it can be referenced/used in the clearFunc subroutine.

```
global entername
```

To make clearFunc() set the value of entername to nothing you must make it set entername's value to "":

```
entername.set("")
```

Also, always put the mainloop at the end of your code.

You also need to define the clearFunc subroutine before you reference it, so i moved it to before the reset button.

The code:

```
main_window_page = Tk()
main_window_page.title("GA")
main_window_page.geometry("600x600")

global entername #make it a global string variable
entername = StringVar()
enterpassword = StringVar()

Username=tk.Label(text="Username")
Username.pack(pady=1,padx=1)
EnterName=tk.Entry(bd=4,textvariable=entername)
EnterName.pack(pady=5,padx=5)

def clearFunc():
    entername.set("")

Reset=tk.Button(text="Reset",command=clearFunc)
Reset.pack(pady=13,padx=13)

main_window_page.mainloop()
```